# Obtener con HTmlUnit el html generado después de un click en un anchor

Tags: html, click

Estoy escrapeando una página con htmlUnit.
Dentro de la página busco un anchor en concreto para hacer click en él y posteriormente obtener el html que genera.

Mi código estaba funcionando hasta ahora pero por algún error ha dejado de funcionar, he comprobado que el anchor que obtengo es correcto y así es. Ahora mismo a pesar de hacer click la web no cambia con lo que el html que obtengo es el mismo que sin hacer click

Os dejo el código por si veis algún error que se me está escapando.

Gracias de antemano

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    String searchQuery = "BetFair" ;

    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);  
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);  
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

     String searchUrl = "https://www.betfair.es/sport/football";


     HtmlPage page = client.getPage(searchUrl);
     HtmlDivision marketWrapper =(HtmlDivision) page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='markets-wrapper']");
     HtmlAnchor htmlAnchor = marketWrapper.getFirstByXPath("//a[@title='La Liga - España']");
     HtmlPage leaguePage = htmlAnchor.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo solventé cambiando a false la opción setJavaScriptEnabled

```
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```